# Problem with nested IfSubStr calls

Tags: tex-core, expansion, xstring, nesting

I have the following code in my preamble:

```
\usepackage{xstring}
\newcommand\myhelpermacro[1]{\IfSubStr{#1}{true}{Text contained the word "cat"}{Text did not contain the word "cat"}}
\newcommand\mymacro[1]{\myhelpermacro{\IfSubStr{#1}{cat}{true}{false}}}
```

When I later try to use `mymacro` in the document, like so:

```
\mymacro{cat}
```

I get the following error:

```
Use of \@xs@IfSubStr@@ doesn't match its definition. \mymacro{cat}
```

Modifying `mymacro` by using `\expandafter`, like so:

```
\newcommand\mymacro[1]{\expandafter\myhelpermacro{\IfSubStr{#1}{cat}{true}{false}}}
```

doesn't help. However, if I instead manually expand the call to `IfSubStr` in `mymacro`, i.e.

```
\newcommand\mymacro[1]{\myhelpermacro{true}}
```

the code works.

What is going on here? Why doesn't my code work without manually expanding `IfSubStr`?

---

**Edit 1:** To clarify my expectations of the behavior of the code, I expect that when I use, e.g.,

```
\mymacro{caterpillar}
```

this expands to

```
\myhelpermacro{\IfSubStr{caterpillar}{cat}{true}{false}}
```

which in turn should expand (since I expect what's inside the brackets to be expanded before what's outside of them, because that's how brackets are supposed to behave, right? :) ) to

```
\myhelpermacro{true}
```

which in turn should expand to `Text contained the word "cat"`.

However, when I use, e.g.,

```
\mymacro{aardvark}
```

I expect this to expand to

```
\myhelpermacro{\IfSubStr{aardvark}{cat}{true}{false}}
```

which in turn should expand to

```
\myhelpermacro{false}
```

which in turn should expand to `Text did not contain the word "cat"`.

---

**Edit 2:** After reading the [`xstring` documentation](http://ftp.acc.umu.se/mirror/CTAN/macros/generic/xstring/xstring_doc_en.pdf) (under *3.2
Expansion of macros, optional argument*), I tried changing the definition of `mymacro`, by storing the result of `IfSubStr` in a temporary variable, to

```
\newcommand\mymacro[1]{\IfSubStr{#1}{cat}{true}{false}[\result]\myhelpermacro{\‌​result}}
```

only to get the following error message when I try to use `mymacro`:

```
Undefined control sequence. \mymacro{cat}
```

Suddenly, LaTeX seems to think `mymacro` isn't defined at all. Why?

---

**Edit 3:** So what I'm trying to do is to define two macros:

The first macro (`myhelpermacro` in this case) that takes a boolean value and inserts a string into the document whose value depends on the value of the boolean.

The second macro (`mymacro` in this case) takes a string and calls the first macro with the boolean `true` if the string contains a specific substring, otherwise it calls the first macro with the boolean `false`.

Since I want to be able to make calls to both macros from the document, both of them need to be defined, and since I want to avoid code duplication, the second macro should call the first macro instead of inserting the string into the document itself.

Comment: When I look at your code, it seems that mymacro calls myhelpmacro with IfSubStr as part of the argument. But myhelpmacro already has IfSubStr in its definition. So, IfSubStr is called within itself.

Comment: There are several questions dealing with the fact that you cannot nest `xstring` macros.

Comment: @egreg Okay; why can't I do that? And how can I solve this in a different but equally powerful way in that case? I want to be able to make calls to `mymacro` and `myhelpermacro`.

Comment: @RobtAll Yes? That is exactly what I'm trying to do. Why shouldn't that work? (@egreg's comment explains why but your answer came before he had given the explanation. Is it obvious for some reason that `xstring` macros cannot be nested?)

Comment: @StrawberryFieldsForever `\IfSubstr{AAA}{A}{true}{false}` is a set of instructions to print `true`, not the string `true`. Some context would help: this seems like an XY question.

Comment: @egreg I'm trying to understand how LaTeX works in its core, which I clearly don't. What do you mean by that `\IfSubstr{AAA}{A}{true}{false}` prints `true` and not the string `true`? Why are `AAA` and `A` interpreted as strings while `true` is not? Is there some reference text for LaTeX that explains this behaviour?

Comment: @StrawberryFieldsForever That depends on how `xstring` works, in particular not by pure expansion. By the way, I don't think it's possible to implement `\IfSubStr` by pure expansion.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63762/discussion-between-strawberryfieldsforever-and-egreg).

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but the key comes down to the fact that the final expansion of a macro cannot be a string, but a series of tokens; though sometimes this series of tokens looks superficially like a string.

Comment: @erreka No, that's not the issue: it's that the implementation of `\IfSubstr` performs assignments, and they cannot be expanded. (This is a general feature of TeX.)

Comment: @JosephWright What *is* an assignment exactly?

Comment: Actually, egreg's and Joseph's comments are right, and made me retract my answer. `\IfSubStr` effectively works by making assignments (`\def`s inside the macro). Whether is this feature what makes us unable to nest `xstring` macros is still beyond my wits.

Comment: @egreg Does my question need further clarification?

Comment: @StrawberryFieldsForever I asked you in chat to clarify what you really need.

Comment: @egreg I saw that, and I tried to do that (in chat as well as in a few edits to my qurstion). So do you still think it needs clarification, and if so, in what way?

Answer (score 1):

With [`functional`](https://ctan.org/pkg/functional) package, composition of functions works as expected if you are familiar with other programming languages such as `Lua` or `JavaScript`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{functional}
\begin{document}

\IgnoreSpacesOn
\PrgNewFunction \mymacro {m} {
  \myhelpermacro{\StrIfInTF{#1}{cat}{\Result{true}}{\Result{false}}}
}
\PrgNewFunction \myhelpermacro {m} {
  \StrIfInTF {#1} {true} {
    \Result{Text ~ contained ~ the ~ word ~ "cat"}
  }{
    \Result{Text ~ did ~ not ~ contain ~ the ~ word ~ "cat"}
  }
}
\IgnoreSpacesOff

\mymacro{caterpillar}

\mymacro{butterfly}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that with this package, you need to pass return values of functions with `\Result` command.